# I seem to only be able to create a 3 column table with python-docx

Tags: python, sqlite, python-docx

I want to create a word file using python-docx.
This word file will have a table where cells are populated by a sqlite3 query.
it all works fine with  1-3 columns, but when i try to add a fourth it does not save anymore. I can add a fourth heading, but as soon as i populate the cells for that fourth heading it does not save anymore. I have tried looking up this problem, but could not find anything. So my question to you is: Is my code correct? Am I overlooking something? If so, what?

```
from docx import Document
import sqlite3

document = Document()
conn = sqlite3.connect('Database.db')
c = conn.cursor()


table = document.add_table(1, 4)

heading_cells = table.rows[0].cells
heading_cells[0].text = 'Description'
heading_cells[1].text = 'Hours/units'
heading_cells[2].text = 'Rate'
heading_cells[3].text = 'Total' #all works well when this is active

Records = (c.execute("SELECT * FROM My_List")).fetchall()
for item in Records:
    cells = table.add_row().cells
    cells[0].text = str(item[1])
    cells[1].text = str(item[2])
    cells[2].text = str(item[3])
    cells[3].text = str(item[4]) #nothing works when this is active

document.save('Demo.docx')
```

Comment: No error/warning traceback? Please post few rows of content of database table. Possibly it is a data issue.

Comment: I just solved it, and your comment about errors made me solve it. (it was a .py file in a separate file that was launched from my main .py file (making me unable to see errors) It was a spacing issue.... I feel so dumb now....Thank You!